# ServiceStack session handling in a Load balanced environment

Tags: session, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack as base library in one of my project.
I have structured my application in two part API and WEB application which are separate project and repository.

Authentication should happen on the API layer and it should be cached there. I am using Ormlite cache client in API Server.

In API AppHost.cs

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("ConnectionString",SqlServerDialect.Provider);
container.RegisterAs<OrmLiteCacheClient, ICacheClient>();
container.Resolve<ICacheClient>().InitSchema();
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new APISession(),
  new IAuthProvider[] {
    new APICredentialsAuthProvider(new AppSettings())
 }));
```

In APICredentialsAuthProvider i am saving session which gets stored in Db in `CacheEntry` table

I am authenticating the user in Web application via ajax call using `apiurl/auth` which return the `AuthenticateResponse` with `sessionId` with it.
I am updating this sessionId to cookie as `s-id` and later in pre request filter based on the request type it is being updated in `ss-id` or `ss-pid`.

```
//Inside Web application apphost
this.PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) =>
{
  System.Net.Cookie cookie = req.Cookies["s-id"];
  req.Cookies["ss-id"] = cookie;
  req.SetSessionId(cookie.Value)
});
```

This approach does not fetch the session from cache which is Ormlite in my case and respective configuration in provided in Web and Api application.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

However i am able to access the session by using cache client

```
//Inside Web application apphost
this.PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) =>
{
  System.Net.Cookie cookie = req.Cookies["s-id"];
  req.Cookies["ss-id"] = cookie;
  req.SetSessionId(cookie.Value);
 APISession cachedSession = GetCacheClient(req).Get<APISession(SessionFeature.GetSessionKey(cookie.Value));
 WEBSession session.PopulateWith<WEBSession, APISession>(cachedSession);

});
```

this works fine and i am able to fetch the session, but by putting this in pre request filter increases the db calls from my web application (on each request).

**Is there any alternate solution available to achieve the same?**

***Thanks in advance!!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are load balancing multiple Web Apps **behind the same domain** then using any of the [distributed Caching Providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) like `OrmLiteCacheClient` will send ServiceStack's `ss-id/ss-pid` Cookies when making a request to either of the Apps:

```
http://example.org/app1 -> http://internal:8001/
                  /app2 -> http://internal:8002/
                  /app3 -> http://internal:8003/
```

Then as long as each app is configured with the same `OrmLiteCacheClient` a Session created in one App would be visible in all 3 Apps.

You can prevent further DB access for retrieving the Session for that request by setting it on `IRequest.Items`, e.g:

```
req.Items[Keywords.Session] = session;
```

Then any access to the Session for that Request will be resolved from the `IRequest` Items Dictionary instead of hitting the DB.

Another alternative Auth solution that will let you authenticate in all 3 Apps is to use the stateless [JWT Auth Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JWT-AuthProvider).